# python: split csv into multiple csv based on date

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date

I am struggling to create multiple csvs from a single csv file based on the `date`.

I have a following sample of a very big csv file:

```
cid      date       pos 
11  2020-01-04  29
11  2020-01-05  29
11  2020-01-06  29
11  2020-01-07  29
11  2020-01-08  29
11  2020-01-09  29
11  2020-01-10  29
12  2020-01-04  31
12  2020-01-05  31
12  2020-01-06  31
12  2020-01-07  31
12  2020-01-08  31
12  2020-01-09  31
12  2020-01-10  31
```

The `cid` and `pos` could be anything, Also there are other column as well.

What I need is to have multiple csv created from the this `master.csv` like:

`2020-01-04.csv` with all the column data from the master.csv with date column `2020-01-04`

then
`2020-01-05.csv` with all the data from the master.csv with date column `2020-01-05`
and so on.

What i tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/master.csv')
cols = df.columns

df['date'] = df['date']

for i in set(df.date):
    filename = "path/"+i+".csv"
    df.loc[df.date == i].to_csv(filename,index=False,columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/master.csv')

for i in set(df['date']):
    df.loc[df['date'] == i].to_csv(f"path/{i}.csv",index=False)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/master.csv')    

for i, g in df.groupby('date'):
    g.to_csv(f"path/{i}.csv",index=False)
```